# How to apply a filter whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: symfony, twig

Basically, I am looking for the filter equivalent of the `attribute()` function for objects and arrays. I want to be able to apply a filter, whose name is stored in a variable.

```
{# 
    This works and is really useful 
    prints object.someVar 
#}
{% set varName = 'someVar' %}
{{ attribute(object,varName) }} 

{#
    The function "filter" does not exist
#}
{% set filterName = 'somefilter' %}
{{ filter(object,filterName) }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reach this goal you have to extend your TwigFilter.

How to initially write you Extension you can read [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Assuming that you have created you extension, you have define your function, let's say `applyFilter`.

```
//YourTwigFilterExtension.php

public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        ...
        'apply_filter' => new \Twig_Function_Method($this, 'applyFilter'),
    );
}
```

Then, you have to define this function

```
public function applyFilter($context, $filterName)
{
    // handle parameters here, by calling the 
    // appropriate filter and pass $context there
}
```

After this manipulations you'll be able to call in Twig:

```
{{ apply_filter(object, 'filterName') }}
```

---

Cheers ;)

Comment: Can you add applyFilter implementation ?